Global sections vs regular sections
I'm having problems with understanding the definition of a global section of a sheaf defined over a scheme $X$. In my head a global section can be thought as a function whose domain is all $X$. But, what if I have a point $P$ and I need to consider the sheaf twisted by $P$? For example, I have a $L-$scheme $(X,O_X)$ and a closed point $P$. Let $F$ be a torsion-free  $O_X-$module and define $F_n=F\otimes O_X(nP)$. How the global sections of $F_n$ looks like? I know that in $O_X(nP)$ are global sections of $O_X$ with poles in $P$ or order at most $n$. Then, How can I have a global section if my sections are allowed to have poles in a point? I read that the term "global" does not necessarily imply that these sections are "regular" everywhere, so, What is the difference between being "global" and being "regular"?
Thanks in advance!

In non-algebraic language, a global holomorphic section of $\mathscr L\otimes \mathscr O_X(nP)$ is a meromorphic section of $\mathscr L$ with a pole of order $\le n$ at $P$.

The notation $\mathcal{O}_X(nP)$ only makes sense if $X$ is a curve. Also, the words "sections of $\mathcal{O}_X$ with poles in $P$" do not make sense, since a function that has a pole is not a section of $\mathcal{O}_X.$

In general scheme theory (so not think about complex varieties, or anything of that sort) global sections are literally just elements in the ring $O_X(X)$. Note that in general it doesn't really make sense to think of these elements having poles.
